# Creating auto back of mongodb using shell script

Tags: mongodb, shell, sh

Here is very basic script to do this. All commands executing correctly but no mongodump can be seen in the directory

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=`date +%m%d%y`
DEST=/db_bk/$DIR
mkdir -p $DEST
mongodump -h localhost -d medicinenet_data -o $DEST
```

Execution

```
 ./bk.sh
2017-01-15T14:29:31.486+0530    writing medicinenet_data.diabetes_mellitus_unique to 
2017-01-15T14:29:31.499+0530    done dumping medicinenet_data.diabetes_mellitus_unique (547 documents)
2017-01-15T14:29:31.511+0530    writing medicinenet_data.diabetes_mellitus to 
2017-01-15T14:29:32.489+0530    done dumping medicinenet_data.diabetes_mellitus (137620 documents)
```

Comment: These commands seem to work for me - are you certain that all of your `DIR` and `DEST` variables are set correctly? Are you able to see the output if you print it to STDOUT? (specify `-o -` to dump to STDOUT). Also is your backup directory created at all?

Comment: @Lix: Thanks, I justed added the full absolute path of the DIR, it worked.

Comment: Thats great to hear :) Perhaps you can consider adding that as an answer to your post? It might just help future visitors facing a similar issue with `mongodump`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by giving full absolute path

I just edited the file path

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=`date +%m%d%y`
DEST=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/db_bk/$DIR
echo $DEST
mkdir -p $DEST
mongodump -h localhost -d medicinenet_data -o $DEST
```

Which worked.